# Require client Digest auth in zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, digest-authentication

I'm using zookeeper 3.6.1, I tried to enable Authentication with Digest scheme.

If the zk Client provides valid credentials, it is authenticated properly.

The issue is if a zk client provides no credentials, it is allowed to pass even then. I found there are options to mandate SASL authentication. Is there anything similar for Digest or some common way to force authentication?

Please assist.